# Regarding Microsoft API: IHTMLWindow2::execScript Method

Tags: html, internet-explorer, msdn, javascript

In MSDN, it is decleared as in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741364(VS.85).aspx :

---

**Syntax**
HRESULT execScript(          BSTR code,
    BSTR language,
    VARIANT *pvarRet
);

**Parameters**
code
[in] BSTR that specifies the code to be executed.
language
[in] BSTR that specifies the language in which the code is executed. The language defaults to Microsoft JScript.
pvarRet
[out, retval] Address of a VARIANT of type VT_EMPTY. This method always returns VT_EMPTY.
Return Value

### **Returns S_OK if successful, or an error value otherwise.**

How to get the Error codes of IHTMLWindow2::execScript() api when it is failing, MSDN is clearly not defined the details of Error Codes in the api definiton pages.

Any information would be very helpful regarding the Error Codes.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just searched for HRESULT: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378137%28VS.85%29.aspx